# Does the word "touch" in Genesis 3:3 orginate from Eve or Satan?

Tags: catholicism, genesis, satan, sexuality, adam-and-eve

**The Serpent's Deception**

> The woman answered the serpent, “We may eat the fruit of the trees of the garden, but of the fruitof the tree in the middle of the garden, God has said, ‘You must not eat of it or touch it, or you will die.’“You will not surely die,” the serpent told her.

https://biblehub.com/genesis/3-3.htm

From the above narration it has an indication that Eve was only prompted to answered the serpent doubtful question.

Is satan suggesting Eve to touch first the fruit in this narration?

We know that satan is a "spiritual being" and only indwelt the serpent, so if satan would touch the fruit first it will be in a form of a "mystical touch", or satan mimicking God's action might "breathe in" to Eve soul to infect or to bring death to her soul.

As we can see from **Genesis 2:7** *Douay-Rheims Bible*

> And the Lord God formed man of the slime of the earth: and breathed into his face the breath of life, and man became a living soul. **(Genesis 2:7)**

This particular narration in Genesis 3:3 follows by the word ***"beguiled"*** by the serpent which means Eve had been deceived into touching the fruit.

We do not know if the serpent "mystically touch" the fruit first just to show Eve that it will bring no harm to her or the punishment that "they will surely die" is not true.

It looks like the serpent knew that Eve will not easily be tempt to eat the fruit at once so he devised a sublte traps for Eve to touch it first.

My question is, is the word "touch" originates from Eve or from satan by way of suggesting Eve to touch the fruit first?

The word "touch" is associated to Eve's virginity.

As the world famous saying is if you are still a virgin the phrase "never been touch".

So can we say, in Genesis 3:3 satan is targeting to destroy the virginity of Eve by way of introducing or suggesting the word "touch".

I'm looking for answers from commentaries or Church Father teaching or even sound biblical interpretation that pertains particularly in the reflections on the words "touching the fruit" and how it is related to the virginity of Eve.

Comment: If Eve was still a virgin when she talked to the serpent then she'd already be a sinner for disobeying God's instructing to breed.

Comment: @curiousdanni there's a time for everything."a time to breed" as you said is also mentioned in genesis. But the highest calling for Adam & Eve first is perfection of virtues or Theosis, this was taught by the Church Fathers. Breeding follows but only after Theosis. Ponder the Wisdom behind Theosis,...what is the offspring of a Man & Woman who achieved perfect divination? have you thought about it? It's an "immaculate child" and the breeding will go on, the cycle of producing an immaculate child..if only the word "touch it" was resisted by Eve.

Comment: Could you clarify why you're assuming any sexual reference or context at all?  I see nothing in the narrative to suggest this is anything other than a tree with fruit on it.  Gen. 2:9 indicates the tree was there before Adam was even placed in the garden (2:15) and certainly before Eve was even created (2:21-22), so how could it be reasonably be tied to the sexuality of humans?

Comment: JDM-GBG It's  still a mystery due to lack of narration. We can only meditate on the nature of punishment. God is Just and He cannot & will not rendered a sentenced unjustly. Adam & Eve was punished, while the serpent suffered severed punishment "a cursed".One more puzzle the ground is "cursed" but not the "Tree of Knowledge of Good & Evil. So, the tree is only a methaphor not a tangible thing.I'm looking for the significance & implication of the word "touch it", as this word does not come from God. So who from Eve or satan and what is the wisdom behind it.That's my specific question.

Comment: @curiousdannii  no mention of breeding until after the fall. No reason to believe eve was not a virgin when she was beguiled by the serpent.

Comment: @marianagustin  the verse you are asking about plainly states “GOD said you must not touch it” God brought the word touch into the equation

Comment: @Kris The mandate/command to fill the earth with their children is there in Genesis 1:28. We can only speculate about how long after creation it took for the serpent to tempt Adam and Eve, but sex and raising children was clearly part of God's design for sinless humanity. With no sin, no defect in the relationship between God and man, no shame between husband and wife, an easy life in God's garden, and a clear instruction from God to reproduce, why wouldn't Adam and Eve have slept together? Whatever would they have to wait for?

Comment: @curiousdannii genesis 4:1    After getting kicked out of garden the first mention of sex relations. Had a child been conceived before original sin it would not have inherited sin  and death  never heard the thought that Adam and Eve were sexually active before the fall. I will investigate

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2534/did-adam-and-eve-not-have-sex-in-the-garden-of-eden. This is an interesting place to start@curiousdannii

Comment: @Kris I never suggested that they successfully conceived a child, only that the idea that Eve was still a virgin implies its own sin because of the command to reproduce.

Comment: @curiousdanni Can you cite where your interpretation came from and who held that teaching that "adam & eve had already have committed sexual acts" in the garden before the serpent tempted Eve? Is that an authoritative teaching or you made it yourself?

Comment: @marian I think it's just a logical inference from the existence of the command and that the eating of the fruit has been considered the first act of sin. Even if you're right about Adam and Eve needing theosis before sin, I see no reason to conclude that would exclude sex. For the sinless married couple there is nothing unvirtuous about sex.

Comment: @curiousdannii  what are the chances that a perfect man and woman would engage in sexual activity for any length of time without a pregnancy?

Comment: @marianagustin, I don't see any way to support the assertion that "the tree is just a metaphor."  It goes completely against the plain sense of the text.  You might as well claim that the whole garden was merely metaphorical (symbolizing the sinless state of humans) and not a real place.

Comment: – JDM-GBG Look at God sentenced, Eve & Adam was punished, the serpent was cursed and even the ground was cursed.The ground? what did the ground do? Remember Jesus in the NT "cursed the fig tree". In here the Tree of Knowledge of Good & Evil or the fruit is not real or tangible.In my understanding the Tree's in the garden  is an expression of physical affection, but the limits of the expression is the Tree of Knowledge.They need to mature first into perfection or Theosis before they can consummate that particular "fruit" or expressed that affection or physical act.

Comment: @marianagustin, so your reasoning is:  Eve was punished, Adam was punished, serpent was cursed, ground was cursed, therefore the trees must be metaphorical.  It's a complete non sequitur. And again it goes against the plain sense of the text of Gen. 2.  "8 Now the Lord God had planted a garden in the east, in Eden; and there he put the man he had formed. 9 The Lord God made all kinds of trees grow out of the ground—trees that were pleasing to the eye and good for food. In the middle of the garden were the tree of life and the tree of the knowledge of good and evil."

Comment: @marianagustin, how could metaphorical trees "grow out of the ground," "be pleasing to the eye", or be "good for food"?  Or how can you read those verses and say well, some/most of those trees are literal, but the other two trees are just metaphors?  It makes no sense.

Comment: JDM-GBG to make sense, can you put your answer on the box. and explain why the tree is only  the "tangible thing" left unpunished or curse?you put a lot of comment.don't you think it would be better to answer the question rather than just commenting?

Comment: @marianagustin, I'm using comments because I can't make any sense of the question (which appears to be based on a stack of a priori assumptions that run contrary to the text).  Answers are for when the question is answerable -- if you have to question the question (which I do and am), then that's what comments are for.

Answer (score 4):

The words originate with Eve.

> Now the serpent was more subtil than any beast of the field which YHVH God had made. And **he said unto the woman**, Yea, hath God said, Ye shall not **eat** of every tree of the garden?
>
> And **the woman said** unto the serpent, We may eat of the fruit of the trees of the garden:
>
> But of the fruit of the tree which is in the midst of the garden, God hath said, Ye shall not eat of it, neither shall ye **touch** it, lest ye die.
>
> And **the serpent said** unto the woman, Ye shall not surely die:
>
> For God doth know that in the day ye **eat** thereof, then your eyes shall be opened, and ye shall be as gods, knowing good and evil.

There are three separate breaks between three separate dialogues.

Nobody says anything about *touching* the fruit except for Eve, so it was either a command from Adam out of fear she would eat it, or she reasoned it in her own head and thought it was true.

Perhaps something for you to consider is that after they eat the fruit, YHVH God says:

> Behold, the man is become **as** one of us, to know good and evil: and now, lest he put forth his hand, and take also of the tree of life, and eat, and live for ever

Eating the fruit was how God accomplished “making man after His *likeness*”, and this involved obtaining the knowledge of good and evil. Why would having sex with a serpent give them this knowledge, or make them *like* God?

Comment: A command from Adam probably, but touching it is not a sin, as God command clearly said "Do not eat". I'm looking the breaks of dialogue that's probably missing. What if, Satan having a hard time convincing Eve to eat the fruit as we know Eve had preternatural gifts too like Adam. So, it might be Eve trying to resist the temptation.So, satan "beguiled" him and suggest, ok "why not try to touch it first" to see if you will really die.Remember that's the way satan operates his attack, slowly but surely and the malice is hidden.Just my thoughts.But your answer is ok.